# How to split specific paragraph in R?

Tags: r, paragraph

I want to extract specific paragraph from a long text.
such as:

```
txt1 <- "What is claimed is:
1. A hybridized CMP conditioner, comprising: a base; 
a first abrasive unit, provided on said base and comprising a first
bonding layer fixed on said base, a substrate for abrasive unit provided     
on said first bonding layer and an abrasive layer provided on said 
substrate for abrasive unit, said abrasive layer being a diamond coating 
formed through a chemical vapor deposition process, and said diamond 
coating being provided on the surface thereof with a plurality of abrasive     
tips. 
2.  The hybridized CMP conditioner according to claim 1, wherein said base
is provided on the surface thereof with a central region and an annular     
outer region around the outside of said central region. 
3.  The hybridized CMP conditioner according to claim 2, wherein said
central region is provided with a recessed portion for said first abrasive
unit to be provided therein, and said annular outer region is provided 
with a plurality of first accommodating portions spaced apart from each 
other for said second abrasive units to be provided therein. "
```

I only want to extract the first paragraph. Like this:

```
1. A hybridized CMP conditioner, comprising: a base; 
a first abrasive unit, provided on said base and comprising a first
bonding layer fixed on said base, a substrate for abrasive unit provided     
on said first bonding layer and an abrasive layer provided on said 
substrate for abrasive unit, said abrasive layer being a diamond coating 
formed through a chemical vapor deposition process, and said diamond 
coating being provided on the surface thereof with a plurality of abrasive     
tips.
```

I have tried use strsplit function to do

```
strsplit(txt1, "\n1.", perl = TRUE)
```

but the result is not what I want.

```
[1] "What is claimed is:"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            

[2] " A hybridized CMP conditioner, comprising: a base; \na first abrasive 
unit, provided on said base and comprising a first bonding layer fixed on 
said base, a substrate for abrasive unit provided on said first bonding 
layer and an abrasive layer provided on said substrate for abrasive unit, 
said abrasive layer being a diamond coating formed through a chemical 
vapor deposition process, and said diamond coating being provided on the 
surface thereof with a plurality of abrasive tips; and \na plurality of 
second abrasive units, provided on said base and comprising a second 
bonding layer fixed on said base, a carrying post provided on said second 
bonding layer, an abrasive particle provided on said carrying post and an 
abrasive material-bonding layer provided between said carrying post and 
said abrasive particle. \n2.  The hybridized CMP conditioner according to 
claim 1, wherein said base is provided on the surface thereof with a 
central region and an annular outer region around the outside of said 
central region. "
```

Comment: `stringr::str_split(txt1, "\n[:digit:]+\\.")`

Comment: You would need few nested `gsub`s to reach final output e.g `gsub("\\s\\s|^\\s+|\\s+$","",gsub("\\s\\s"," ",gsub("\n"," ",unlist(strsplit(txt1,"[0-9][.]"))[2])))`

Answer (score 0):

Using `strsplit`:

```
 # split at newline followed by number and '.'
paragraphs <- unlist(strsplit(txt1, "\\n(?=(\\d+\\. ))", perl = TRUE))
 # get rid of newlines and select 1st paragraph
gsub(" *\\n", " ", paragraphs)[2]
```